# How can I make this code more elegant?

Tags: scala

I have the following function:

```
private def solveError(hostIp: String, command: String) = {
  commandSlave(hostIp, "STOP SLAVE") match {
    case Success(x) => commandSlave(hostIp, command) match {
      case Success(y) => commandSlave(hostIp, "START SLAVE") match {
        case Success(z) => Success(z)
        case Failure(ex) => Failure(ex)
      }
      case Failure(ex) => Failure(ex)
    }
    case Failure(ex) => Failure(ex)
  }
}
```

I think there must be a more elegant way to write this function but I'm not sure how. Using nested match cases doesn't feel right to me but I'm new to Scala and I don't know if there is a better way. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: may be better suited for codereview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `commandSlave` returns `Try`, `flatMap` is what you want:

```
commandSlave(hostIp, "STOP SLAVE")
  .flatMap(_ => commandSlave(hostIp, command))
  .flatMap(_ => commandSlave(hostIp, "START SLAVE"))
```

From scaladocs of `flatMap` of `Try`:

> Returns the given function applied to the value from this Success or returns this if this is a Failure.

Also you can use `for` comprehension here, which internally desugars to the same sequence of `flatMap`s:

```
private def solveError(hostIp: String, serverHost: Host, backHost: Host, command: String) = 
  for {
    _ <- commandSlave(hostIp, "STOP SLAVE")
    _ <- commandSlave(hostIp, command)
    z <- commandSlave(hostIp, "START SLAVE")
  } yield z
```

Comment: Maybe you could also show how to transform this to a for comprehension ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it looks so much better. Thanks!